# Why does the result of a linear fit differ in R and Excel(Gnumeric Spreadsheet and WPS) with the same small data?

Tags: r, excel, data-fitting

I have encountered a strange problem when I do a simple linear fit for my data in R and Excel-like Spreadsheet software e.g. Gnumeric Spreadsheet and WPS.

the data below is 19 pairs of x and y

```
93.37262737 56200
101.406044  62850
89.27322677 56425
86.9458042  43325
70.54645355 42775
85.1936032  38375
72.10985    38376
73.54055944 22950
78.092  15225
71.30285    12850
70.03953023 18125
66.31068931 14200
93.39847716 13925
66.09695152 13225
70.6549 18125
76.43348868 14125
71.37531234 14875
85.7953977  19275
95.65012506 45375
```

and is saved in a file called 'data.csv'

I do a linear fit between x and y. R script is below :

```
data<-read.csv("data.csv",col.names=c("x","y"))

# plot data
plot(data$x,data$y)
#Fit
lmodelx<-lm(data$y~data$x)
abline(lmodelx)

summary(lmodelx)
```

which gives this result:

```
Call:
lm(formula = data$y ~ data$x)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-27855  -7151  -1314   6947  23014 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -48212.8    23691.0  -2.035  0.05876 . 
data$x         963.5      296.8   3.246  0.00506 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 13240 on 16 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3971,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3594 
F-statistic: 10.54 on 1 and 16 DF,  p-value: 0.005061
```

You can see that the Multiple R-squared:  0.3971,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.3594,  and the  Coefficients for the Intercept is -48212.8 and the slope is 963.5342. So the formula is y = 963.5342 * x + -48212.8 and Adjusted R-squared (R2) is 0.3594.

But if I do fit the model in Gnumeric Spreadsheet the result is :

[image: Gnumeric Spreadsheet Fiting Result]

Which says the formula should be y = 1052.88214782179 *x + -54588.8186095881 and R2 =

If I fit the model with  WPS Spredsheet, the result is :

[image: WPS]

That also says the formula should be y = 1052.9x - 54589 and R2 = 0.44763

In Excel the result is :

[image: Excel]

The formula is also y = 1052.x - 54589 and R2 = 0.447.

So the question comes that how a well-defined process like such simple fitting can be different in R than other software?

Because in my opinion this least square fitting is already defined, So why does R do this differently?

And what should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your summary data I would say you lost a row in R somewhere since you only have 16 degrees of freedom.  Running your data I get the answer below which matches the other spreadsheet results.

```
Call:
lm(formula = data$y ~ data$x)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-29824  -6660  -1028   8520  23087 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -54588.8    22859.7  -2.388  0.02882 * 
data$x        1052.9      283.7   3.712  0.00173 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 13250 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4476,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4151 
F-statistic: 13.78 on 1 and 17 DF,  p-value: 0.001733
```

Comment: read.csv, has header=TRUE as the default.  So the original code is using the first line of data as column names thus the 1 less row of data and a different regression model.

Comment: @Dave2e yeah it is the problem if I change it into header = FALSE the answer is right. And it is interesting to find that it seems all those spreadsheet use Multiple R-squared as R2 not adjusted R2.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answers are actually "the same" if you use the same data as pointed out by gtwebb. But if you ask "which one to use" then there is one important thing to notice: excel got it wrong. It can't do rounding correctly. It says

```
y = 1052.x - 54589 ... and
R2 = 0.447
```

But this is wrong. Intercept, as calculated by R, is 1052.882 - you can round it to 1053 or 1052.9 or 1052.88 but there's no way you can get `1052` or `1052.`. And R2, as calculated by R, is 0.4476318 - you can round it to 0.45 or 0.448 or 0.4476 but there's no way you can say 0.447 is the correct value. I can't get how it could find the correct rounded value for the intercept (-54588.819 -> -54589), perhaps you've made a mistake somewhere?

In any case, the message is clear: don't use excel for any computations (it's ok for data entry).

Comment: Thank you, And It happened that I got the mistake as @gtwebb said, read.csv is header=TRUE by default. But Thank you anyway. Yeah I should use R and use it correctly.

Comment: not necessarily R -- eg gnumeric doesn't seem to make these gross errors that Excel does - linear regression (as well as rounding!:) is something fairly   basic and you should get the same results regardless of the software

Comment: Yes, when I finally found where is wrong all the results are perfectly fit each other